# App running in background despite plist saying not to

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In my appname-Info.plist

I have 'Application does not run in background' box checked.(it is ticked)

But when i press the button under the screen to close the app, and then double press the button it shows the list of apps and my app is there among the list of currently running apps. Does this mean that my app is running in the background?

If so is there a fix for this? I'd like to make sure my app is completely dead when user quits it.

Thanks
-Code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your app is not running in the background after you close it.
Even if you see it in the switcher app list.

Application has different states

1. Active
2. InActive
3. Running in Background

Your application become in-active, not running in background.

Aplications are allaowd to run in the background only for:

1. Playing music.
2. Navigation needs.
3. VOIP (as Skype).

And you should explicitly ask the permission and set the appropriate code for doing that and not only check the 'Application does run in background' in the info.plist

Answer (score 1):

The list you get when you double tap the home button is not a running applications list. That's a common misconception. It's actually a list of recently launched applications. Therefore it makes sense for your app to be in it even if it doesn't multitask.